# When i debug my app real phone it works really slow

Tags: android, xml, crash, lag

I have tired to debug my app many times with my phone. I have HTC one M8 and my app is working really slow and then it crashes when i drag down the list view which contains pictures of different products. However in emulator its working fine and doesn't even crash. I am using nexus 6 API 23 in emulator.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is that why the app is running slow on my phone? @Carcigenicate